# Module build failed: GraphQLError

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

I couldn't understand the error , I added `graphq-tag` to parse the `.graphql` in webpack config file as shown below

```
{
  test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'graphql-tag/loader'
}
```

The Following is my `.graphql` file

```
import {gql} from 'react-apollo';

const query = gql`
  query {
    userCurrent{
      profile {
      name
    }
    appRoles,
    username,
    authEmail {
      address
    }
    orgs {
      userOrgRoles
      orgId
      name
      orgRoles
    }
    currentOrg {
      orgId
      userOrgRoles
      name
      orgRoles
    }
  }
}`;

export default query;
```

**ERROR**

```
ERROR in **./src/modules/goin_users/client/graphql_queries/user_graphql_queries.graphql
[2] Module build failed: GraphQLError**
[2]     at syntaxError (/home/sairam/Downloads/goin/goin/node_modules/graphql-tag/bundledParser.js:1349:16)
[2]     at unexpected (/home/sairam/Downloads/goin/goin/node_modules/graphql-tag/bundledParser.js:1043:34)
[2]     at parseDefinition (/home/sairam/Downloads/goin/goin/node_modules/graphql-tag/bundledParser.js:206:10)
[2]     at parseDocument (/home/sairam/Downloads/goin/goin/node_modules/graphql-tag/bundledParser.js:160:23)
[2]     at parse (/home/sairam/Downloads/goin/goin/node_modules/graphql-tag/bundledParser.js:97:11)
[2]     at parseDocument (/home/sairam/Downloads/goin/goin/node_modules/graphql-tag/index.js:125:16)
[2]     at gql (/home/sairam/Downloads/goin/goin/node_modules/graphql-tag/index.js:158:10)
[2]     at Object.module.exports (/home/sairam/Downloads/goin/goin/node_modules/graphql-tag/loader.js:27:18)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.graphql` file should contain plain query only, not javascript code:

```
query {
    userCurrent{
      profile {
      name
    }
    appRoles,
    username,
    authEmail {
      address
    }
    orgs {
      userOrgRoles
      orgId
      name
      orgRoles
    }
    currentOrg {
      orgId
      userOrgRoles
      name
      orgRoles
    }
}
```

Then just import it:

```
import query from './query.graphql';

console.log(query);
// {
//   "kind": "Document",
// ...
```

`graphql-tag` loader will handle the rest.

Having just plain query in separate file allows you to get advantages of query highlighting and autosuggestions directly in the code-editor you use:

- Plugin for [VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kumar-harsh.graphql-for-vscode)
- Plugin for [Atom](https://atom.io/packages/language-graphql)

Comment: thanks , I figured it too looking at `https://github.com/apollographql/GitHunt-React`